# Enterprise Architect Image Asset update image not working

Tags: enterprise-architect

I've tried to use a feature in Enterprise Architect which is to change the actual image in an image asset element, but it doesn't seem to work.
I add an image as an image asset.  Then I right-click the element and select "Update Stored Image".  After that the current image is replaced by some sort of placeholder.  The new image is not shown.  I know the nbew image is there because when I double click the element a viewer opens and shows the new image.  It just doesn´t show on the diagram.
I´ve tried closing and opening the app without success.
Another strange thing I noticed is that when right-clicking, the option Show Owned Image is de-selected but even if I reselect it, it won't remain selected.
Has anyone had this problem, and might know how to solve it?
Thanks!
-Jaime

Comment: Which version of Enterprise Architect are you using ? I tried your scenario in EA13.5 and it works good

Comment: I'm using 13.5 Build 1352

Answer (score 5):

I just tried it in EA 13.5 and it works as excepted for me .

**Steps i did :**

1. Import an image using Import Manager.
   [image]
2. Select the image which is imported and click “Convert to Image Asset”. It will create an image artifact in the repository.

[image]

3. Then select the image artifact from diagram -> Update Stored Image
   -> Select a diagram from desktop and selected new image is getting assigned to the existing image artifact.
   [image]

Once given the confirmation , Image will be updated

[image]

HTH

Arshad

Comment: Hello Arshad, thanks for your detailed explanation  and help.  I tried your approach but got the same result.  I think, however that I might have the cause.  I think this is only happening when using PNG files.  When using 
 BMP and JPG I´ve got no issue.  So for now I'll avoid PNG files.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helps @Jimmy